# How to merge individual commits from another branch without side effects (aka without using cherry-pick)?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

A client wanted a customized version of our product, so we branched our `master` branch into a `client` branch. However, I ended up making important changes on `client`, and now I'd like to merge them back into `master`. These comprise approximately 20 commits (out of, say, 200), some adjacent but mostly spread randomly through the branch's commit log.

I know `git cherry-pick` was designed for this, but I get the impression it does not preserve commit history, and it seems to ignore commit logs, which I'd rather not copy & paste 20 times. I would also like to avoid problems when merging any further `master` changes **back** into `client`, which I'm sure we will need to do as we develop our product and wish to merge those new features and bugfixes into the custom client version.

Is there a way to merge these 20 commits while preserving easy mergeability and retaining original commit messages?

Answer (score 3):

`cherry-pick` is the right instrument. You could merge the master back (better doing it right after cherry-picking) and if the changes are identical, you will not get any conflicts, everything will be merged back quite easy. Of course, if during cherry-picking you would be resolving conflicts, you may have conflicts too during merging back. But no easy solution here.

Worth to mention that VCS is for versioning during development, client-branching is not the best approach. Better would be using build tools to make different builds for different clients, so one VCS revision should be used for building an application for all clients.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the build tools idea? We use branches for client projects extensively.

Comment: @SamBallantyne Depends on infrastructure you are using. The idea is you should use language level (e.g. SomeInterface implemented by ClientAImpl and ClientBImpl) and probably custom project configurations, #ifdef-#else,  plug-in architecture, etc. In this case while you developing a project you could see how particular piece of code works for all clients - you don't need to switch branches, etc.

Comment: So, to clarify, different repositories for each client project?

Comment: @SamBallantyne No, only single repository. Probably only single branch as `master`. More branches could occur if you have multiple versions of your product. E.g. you have released v1.0 and working on a v2.0 and you need a hotfix applied to v1.0 as everybody uses it now, but v2.0 is still in development.

Answer (score 2):

I think [kan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33269828/1256452) answers your question, and this would be a comment, but as a comment it winds up too long, and is impossible to format:

> I know git cherry-pick was designed for this, but I get the impression it does not preserve commit history

History, in git, is formed by the commit graph.  Cherry-picking an existing commit copies the *changes* made in that commit, making a new commit<sup>1</sup> (usually with a different parent commit ID, different committer time stamp, and quite possibly a different source tree as well).  To copy changes, git simply compares that commit against its parent,<sup>2</sup> resulting in a patch, then applies the patch to the current `HEAD` commit<sup>3</sup> and makes a new commit (appending to the current `HEAD`) from the result.

If you want to keep a record of which commit was cherry-picked, the `-x` flag tells `git cherry-pick` to add the source commit ID to the log message.  This is a bit painful to use (and relies on no one "rewriting history" to remove that commit), but does work for tracking down the original commit.

> and it seems to ignore commit logs ...

The default is to copy the log of the copied commit (and then allow you to edit that), so I don't know why you'd say this.

---

<sup>1</sup>If the parent of the cherry-picked commit is also the current (`HEAD`) commit, `git cherry-pick --ff` will simply adjust the `HEAD` via fast-forwarding.  You could use this yourself, but I think it's mainly intended as a helper for interactive rebase.

<sup>2</sup>This assumes a regular (non-root, non-merge) commit.  To cherry-pick a merge, which has multiple parents, you must tell `git cherry-pick` which parent it should use here.  When cherry-picking a root commit git now automatically compares with an empty tree so that every file is newly created, which is the right semantic (although I think it's rare to really want to cherry-pick a root commit in the first place).

<sup>3</sup>There are nuances here with using `-n`, which allows you to jam many "cherries" into a single commit.  But if you don't use `-n`, you can ignore these, just like you can ignore `--ff` if you don't use it.